# Show a C-infinity function is a polynomial

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, polynomials, baire-category

> Suppose $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(N)}(x)=0$. Show that $f$ is a polynomial.

This is from one of the Analysis qualifying exam problems. I can show there exists an interval $(a,b)$ on which $f$ is a polynomial by using Baire category theorem, but I can't extend it to the real line. Any suggestion?

I think I get some new ideas about this problem. First I can find an interval $I=(a,b)$ by using Baire theorem (same idea from the question that Clement C. added.) where $f$ coincides with a polynomial $g$ on $I$. Then we consider $f^{(i)}(a), i\leq N_g$ where $N_g$ is the degree of $g$. We must have $f^{(N_g)}(a)=0$ because $f^{(i)}(a^+)=f^{(i)}(a)=g^{(i)}(a), i\in\mathbb{N}$. So if we apply the Taylor's theorem at $x=a$, we can extend $I=(a,b)$ to $I_\epsilon=(a-\epsilon,b)$ such that $f=g$ on $I_\epsilon$. Following the same idea, we can show that
$$\inf\{a:f=g \text{  on  } (a,b) \}=-\infty$$
Similarly we can show $f=g$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Update: I just found that the idea above might not work after I was trying to write down a rigorous proof. The main problem is $C^\infty$ function is not neccesarily analytic. (For example, let $f(x)=0$ on $(-\infty,0]$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ on $(0,\infty)$). So I can only extend $(a,b)$ to some larger (or equal) interval $(c,d)$ if I only use the $C^\infty$ property. So the claim above
$$\inf\{a:f=g \text{  on  } (a,b) \}=-\infty$$
might not be true.

I really have no idea how to extend this interval to the real line now.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/UbNUvB3uGvE

Comment: Take intervals $[-n,n]$. $f$ is a polynomial on every such interval. Can it be a different polynomial restricted to them?

Comment: @Berci How do you get this $[-n,n]$ statement?

Comment: According the MO link from the first comment, we can use the Baire cat. thm on any closed interval. Or, what is your proof of existence of $(a,b)$?

Comment: @Berci I am not saying your hint is wrong, just that I don't see how to get there (and, for the record, I would not know how to answer the OP's question -- I only know it is a not-so-easy, rather classic one). But for instance, if you are to use the existence of an open interval $(a,b)$ (as the OP's seem to know how to prove there is such), then applying this technique to intervals $[-n,n]$ for $n\geq 1$: what would prevent all "these $(a,b)$'s" to be the *same* interval for each $n$? (as the $[-n,n]$ are included in one another)

Comment: Let $S_n=\{x: f^{(n)}=0\}.$ Then $S_n$ is closed. Let $J$  be any closed real interval of non-zero length.  We have  $J=\cup_n(J\cap S_n)$ so by Baire, there exists $n$ such that $int (J\cap S_n)\ne \emptyset.$ Hence $T=\cup_n int (S_n)$ is dense in $\mathbb R .$  And if $x\in T$ then $f|_I $ is a polynomial for some open interval $ I $ containing $  x. $ ... I'm  not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answers to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial.

There the question only asks for a proof of the result for $f \in C^\infty([0,1])$. However, most of the answers also work for $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. In particular, the accepted answer also solves the problem when replacing $[0,1]$ by $\mathbb R$.